# Figure 7.7. and 7.8 in Loring Tu's An Introduction to manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, projective-space

Figure 7.7 and 7.8 are showed as follows in Loring Tu's *An Introduction to manifolds*:
[image]
[image]

However, I cannot understand why $\mathbb RP^2$ cannot be embedded as a submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$. The  the orientation of the boundary of Fig7.7 and Fig 7.8 seems not the same, how do they relate to each other? I would appreciate it if someone could explain this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first of the four subfigures of Figure 7.8, the author has taken the liberty of breaking the boundary of the disc into four segments instead of just two, and has labelled how to identify those four segments in pairs. But if you compare that with the identifications shown in Figure 7.7, you'll see that what actually happens *in both cases* is that each point on the circle is identified with the antipodally opposite point of the circle. So the identifications in Figure 7.7 and the first subfigure of 7.8 are really identical, hence both yield $\mathbb RP^2$.

What happens in the next three subfigures of Figure 7.8, though, is that certain additional identifications are taking place in order to get a map into $\mathbb R^3$: besides the antipodally opposite 2-to-1 A,C identification, and the antipodally opposite 2-to-1 B,D identification, the remaining points on the circle are identified 4-to-1. That means that the induced map $\mathbb R P^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ has certain 2-to-1 identifications and hence is not injective.

But that only raises the question: Why isn't there some other continuous function $\mathbb R P^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ which **is** injective? Well, there isn't any such function. Proving it takes some substantial work in algebraic topology, and it's not immediately obvious how to prove it. But that's really beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: "the remaining points on the circle are identified 4-to-1" could you please point out which  these points are?

Comment: In the third subfigure of Figure 7.8, move down on both sides of $D$ a tiny amount to reach 2 points near $D$; also, move down on both sides of $B$ the same tiny amount to reach 2 points near $B$; those four points are identified to a single point in the fourth subfigure.

Comment: In that same fashion, the four open arcs $CD$, $AD$, $AB$, $CB$ are identified 4-to-1 in the fourth sub-figure.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to see it if, instead of an equator, you remove a square from $S^2$, identifying the opposite sides (which will have opposite orientations). This is what you see in figure 7.8. The double arrows correspond to a pair of opposite sides of the square and the single ones to the other pair. When you identify them, you end up with the last figure in 7.8, which shows that you necessarily have self intersections (all the points on the vertical segments are double)